# Parameter substitution with date

Tags: bash, shell

I've got a function that takes an optional date argument, and does calculations based on it. I'm trying to make sure that if that argument isn't provided, the current date/time is used as a default. I've tried this half a dozen ways, but I keep coming back to

```
${testDate:=$(date)}
```

Which works. The value of testDate is properly set, and the rest of the function works properly. However, I get an error message thrown with it:

```
Wed: command not found
```

(The date string is "Wed Mar 9 20:16:48 EST 2016" as of right now)

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to do this?

Edit: To clarify, I'm emulating this, which works fine elsewhere in my script:

```
${menuTitle:=$"Choose from the Menu"}
```

How specifically is the line I posted at the top different from this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical approach in this situation is to use [the null utility (builtin), `:`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_16_01), as it both expands and ignores its arguments:

```
: "${testDate:=$(date)}"  # double quotes not strictly required
```

<sup>While it won't make a difference in most scenarios, the double quotes eliminate unnecessary *additional* expansions, such as pathname expansion and word splitting.</sup>

Even though expansion `${testDate:=$(date)}` expands to the effective value of `$testDate` - whether it had a previous nonempty value or was just initialized to the output from `date` - that value is ignored by `:`, resulting in the desired conditional initialization *only*.

Without `:`, with `${testDate:=$(date)}` used as a statement *by itself*, Bash interprets whatever the expansion results in as a *command*, which in your case resulted in the attempt to execute the output from `date` as a command, which obviously failed (the first whitespace-separated token, `Wed`, was interpreted as the command name).

Note that the above is POSIX-compliant, so it therefore works not only in Bash, but in all major POSIX-compatible shells (`bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, `zsh`).

Comment: Although this is shorter, I can't help but feel it isn't very readable or as instantly recognisable as just conditionally setting the variable, but then again, I don't write shell scripts every day, so maybe I'm biased.

Comment: @dreamlax: If fully agree that it is obscure to the uninitiated, but it's also _idiomatic_ to shell scripts; even if you opt not to use it yourself, it helps to at least recognize and understand the construct.

Comment: @dreamlax I could understand that. For whatever reason, the syntax for shell conditionals continues to befuddle me (I'm used to writing them for C). For me, this is actually MORE obvious.

Comment: @mklement0 I did not realize that the null utility could take arguments (or I had forgotten - it's been a while since I did shell scripting), so that is hugely helpful. I'm still confused as to why the example in my edit DIDN'T cause a problem though.

Comment: @Bryan: Was `${menuTitle:=$"Choose from the Menu"}` really used as a stand-alone statement, or did it serve as an argument to a command or was it used inside a conditional? As a stand-alone statement, the only reason for not seeing an error message I can think of is that either `$menuTitle` had a preexisting, nonempty, but _blank_ (whitespace only) value, or a value of `:`, or, if `$menuTitle` was empty, the localized version of `$"Choose from the Menu"` expanded to such a value (note the rare use of `$"..."`, which is a localizable string).

Comment: Yes. It was a stand-alone statement. The previous line (excluding comments and blank lines) was a shift statement. Unless the value was set by parsing the options, `$menuTitle` should have been unset.

I imagine the difference has something to do with the double quotes, but I don't understand what it is.

Comment: @Bryan: You can try to debug the script by adding the following line before the expansion in question: `PS4='>$LINENO: '; set -vx` - this will show source lines as they're being read and the expanded commands that get executed. If no `>{line-num}:` statement immediately follows the expansion, then it effectively expanded to an empty or all-blank string.

Comment: @Bryan: If the mystery still isn't solved and you're still curious, I suggest you ask a _new_ question, ideally containing an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks! That won't be necessary. It turns out that when I put in the set, I saw it happening there too. Mystery solved: there was no mystery. I was just clearing the output too quickly afterwards to see it previously.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this line:

```
${testDate:=$(date)}
```

not only assigns `testDate` a value but the variable is evaluated as well, and consequently executed as a command.

You can just do:

```
if [ -z "${testDate}" ]; then
    testDate=$(date)
fi
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
[ -z "${testDate}" ] && testDate=$(date)
```

Comment: I'm vaguely familiar with the -z operator, though I haven't been able to find a good reference that explains them in detail. Why is testDate both bracketed and quoted in your example though?

Comment: @Bryan: you may be able to find documentation if you look at `man test` or maybe even `man [`. The `-z` just means to check for a zero-length string. It is important to quote the variable because if you don't, and the variable is empty, then the `-z` operator will have no operand.

Comment: The variable is bracketed only because it's a habit of mine. In this particular case, it is not necessary.

Comment: That's perfect! I don't know why I didn't think of seaching for the test man page.